# Sum the values of a series in pandas based on one of multiple keys?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with pandas in python, and I have a pandas Series object, that I can't for the life of me figure out. it essentially looks like this:

```
>>>print(series_object)

key1              key2      key3                                                             
First class       19438     Error1:0       117
                  16431     Error2:0       80
                  1         Error3:0       70
Second class      28039     Error4:0       65
Third class       2063      Error5:0       28
                  19439     Error6:0       25
Fourth class      25975     Error7:0       11
Fifth class       23111     Error8:0       7
                  1243      Error9:665     4
                            Error9:581     3
                  27525     Error10:0      3
                  1243      Error9:748     2
                  1247      Error11:65     2
                  1243      Error9:852     2
                  1247      Error11:66     2
                            Error11:70     1
                            Error11:95     1
                            Error11:181    1
                            Error11:102    1
                            Error11:160    1
```

I want a way to sum the values of this object where key2 matches, so that it changes `series_object` to be:

```
>>>print(series_object)
key1              key2      key3                                                             
First class       19438     Error1:0       117
                  16431     Error2:0       80
                  1         Error3:0       70
Second class      28039     Error4:0       65
Third class       2063      Error5:0       28
                  19439     Error6:0       25
Fourth class      25975     Error7:0       11
Fifth class       23111     Error8:0       7
                  1243      Error9:665     11
                  27525     Error10:0      3
                  1247      Error11:65     9
```

I've tried a lot of different things, and in a normal array, this wouldn't be an issue for me, but the pandas series object is new and confusing me. Could anyone provide some help?

Comment: What are the rows with blank entries for key 2? As in the last 5 rows under 1247. Are they supposed to be for 1247?

Comment: Yeah, they have the same key2. I'm not sure why it outputs like that, but until there's a different key, it keeps it blank

Comment: should just be able to do  groups = df.groupby(['key2', 'key3']) then counts = groups.sum() or something to that effect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use groupby.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-with-multiindex

In your case

```
series_object.groupby(level='key2').sum()
```

Or if you want to keep 'key1' information as well

```
series_object.groupby(level=['key1', 'key2']).sum()
```

Comment: thanks that works! Is it possible to do this while keeping the first value that appears of key3? So if there's two values where key2 matches, just keep the first value's key3?